# o.s.b.a.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

We have a spring boot 2.7.3 app. It runs fine when invoked from Maven like this:

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

But when we build a fatjar using the shade plugin and try to invoke the application using `java`, we get this error (showing the innermost exception):

```
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:182)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder(DataSourceProperties.java:123)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:90)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 42 common frames omitted
```

Our `application.properties` is like this:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.TeradataDialect
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:teradata://TD1/TMODE=ANSI,CHARSET=UTF8
spring.datasource.password=
```

and in our `pom.xml` we have:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.teradata.jdbc</groupId>
      <artifactId>terajdbc4</artifactId>
      <version>17.20.00.12</version>
    </dependency>
```

*We also unpacked the fatjar and verified `com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver` is contained in it*. When we built the fatjar we could see below in Maven output:

```
[INFO] Including com.teradata.jdbc:terajdbc4:jar:17.20.00.12 in the shaded jar.
```

Why is it then saying Failed to determine a suitable driver class? How can we fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugged this for many hours. The error is not because it cannot find `com.teradata.jdbc:terajdbc4:jar`, its because the `application.properties` was not making it through. We thought it was reading `application.properties` but it wasn't. In our case we were building the fatjar using the shade plugin as mentioned in the question. It turns out the fatjar should be built using the *`spring-boot-maven-plugin`* as explained [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-repackage-vs-mvn-package). Specifically you have to be careful to use:

```
mvn clean package spring-boot:repackage
```

In the first case (using the `shade` plugin), the `application.properties` is under the root directory of the jar file. In the second case (using `spring-boot-maven-plugin`), the root directory contains

```
 % ls                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         temp/td-atr-api2 SIJAIN2-M-89PB
BOOT-INF META-INF org
```

and application.properties is under `BOOT-INF/classes/application.properties`. the organization is very different.